# html text not showing in safari for windows

Tags: css, html, safari

I have noticed a HTML issue that i have never seen before with Safari for Windows Browser.  I have a phone number displayed on the top of a website i have just completed. Here is the simple code;

```
<div id="top-contact"><img src="images/phone-spinner.GIF" alt="">&nbsp;&nbsp;+66 (0)00-000-000</div>
```

This displays as you would expect in all the major browsers, except Safari for Windows Browser. It just displays the following with no phone number;

+()--

Any ideas???

Thanks

Comment: Does it help to close your img tag? <div id="top-contact"><img src="images/phone-spinner.GIF" alt="" />&nbsp;&nbsp;+66 (0)00-000-000</div>

Comment: HTML 5 doesn't require that

Comment: Try it
<a href="tel:1-408-555-5555">1-408-555-5555</a>

Comment: No, that is not working either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use pre tag for numbers. All the browsers support pre tag